# Wrapping mulitple levels of headers (h1 h2 h3) in a list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper

I am new to JS and Jquery and wanted help with the following problem.

I am writing a simple user guide online on a single page and have 3 levels of headers - h1, h2, h3 all in  tags.
I want to dynamicaly generate a side navigation bar using Jquery on my page showing all my heading (h1, h2 h3) nested in a UL list format like below.

```
<ul class = “nav nav-stacked fixed”>
  <li> <a class= '.h1'></a>
    <ul class= “nav nav-stacked”>
        <li> <a class ='.h2'></a>
             <ul class = “nav2 nav-stacked”>
                <li><a class= '.h3'></a> </li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    <ul>
</li> </ul>
```

Currently I have writen the following Jquery

```
$('#sidebar a.h1').wrap('<ul class="nav nav-stacked"><li></li></ul>').addClass('nav nav-stacked');
 $('#sidebar a.h2').wrap('<ul><li><ul class="nav2 nav-stacked"><li></li></li></ul></ul>').addClass('nav2 nav-stacked');
  $('#sidebar a.h3').wrap('<ul><li><ul><li><ul class="nav3 nav-stacked"><li></li></ul></li></li></ul></ul>').addClass('nav3 nav-stacked');});
```

However the result is not returning all the a.h1, a.h2, a.h3 in a single  but listing them seprately

Any guidance or help will be really appreciated.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your html is `<a class= '.h1'></a>`. There shouldn't be `.` in class here. It should be like `<a class= 'h1'></a>`.

Your complete html will be like below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked fixed">
    <li>
        <a class='h1'></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
            <li>
                  <a class='h2'></a>
                  <ul class="nav2 nav-stacked">
                      <li><a class='h3'></a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes your write thank you, however, Can you help me with the Jquery, I am struggling to write the jquery that would wrap all the HTML headers (h1 h2 h3) in the format you just described.

Comment: Jquery code you have written will work fine once you update your html.